# Facebook login exeption in asp core version 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-login

Im setting up a Facebook login in an asp core 3 application.
When I click on Facebook login button the site redirects to Facebook login page, but when it redirects back, I get this exception page:

Method not found: 'System.Text.Json.JsonDocument System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(System.String, System.Text.Json.JsonReaderOptions)'

This is the code:

1. add the service in startup

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
            });
```

2. Add details in user secret:

```
{
  "Authentication:Facebook:AppId": "000000000000",
  "Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret": "0000ada00000asasd00"
}
```

The regular authentication process works just fine.
Only when I try to login with Facebook I am getting this error.

Also, I read about that JSON Support in .NET Core 3.0 is still not finished,
so I tried to use NewtonsoftJson package, but the problem not solved.

Comment: Can you add the line it throws an error?

Comment: hi, thanks for your response. i updated mu question: when user click on facebook login button,  site redirect to facebook login page, but when it  redirect back, he get this exeption

Comment: Could you set breakpoint to check where makes the exception and share the line which makes the error?